# The page isn't redirecting properly in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

page is redirecting and the URL is changing but I'm still getting this error from Firefox.

> ERROR : The page isn't redirecting properly
>   Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

**I have written this code in route file  of Laravel 5**

```
$test_login = "/test/";
if (preg_match($test_login,Request::url())){
    echo $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/test/login";
    header("Location: ".$actual_link);
    die();
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: `header("Location: ".$actual_link);` Ahh, does your `$actual_link` has what it shows I mean you did echo but you wont be seeing it until you _comment_ the header.

Comment: and what are you getting from your `echo`? comment out the header call to find out

Comment: maybe $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] is considered as a string and it is treated as url!

Comment: in echo m getting          http:// localhost:8000/test/login

Comment: and when you hit `*/test/login/` it keeps trying to redirect to the same page. that's why you're getting the error. You need to rethink what you're tying to accomplish. Maybe if you showed us the complete Route we could help you better. And @TooCooL, no. you're completely wrong.

Comment: @ElefantPhace yeah you are right because it matches always the /test/ in the login so it redirects.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Ahh, I see how it works. khair, I find peace and satisfaction when someone appreciates my effort so Ill just keep going x) cheers